# Fetching the previous heading h3 using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

i have a question regarding jquery.
Here is the sample :

```
<h3>Question 1</h3>
<input type="hidden" id="getques" value="" name="ques1">
<input type="radio" id="banswer1" name="answer1" onclick="getvalue()" value="1">
<input type="radio" id="banswer1" name="answer1" onclick="getvalue()" value="2">
<input type="radio" id="banswer1" name="answer1" onclick="getvalue()" value="3">

<h3>Question 2</h3>
<input type="hidden" id="getques" val="" name="ques2">
<input type="radio" id="banswer2" name="answer2" onclick="getvalue()" value="1">
<input type="radio" id="banswer2" name="answer2" onclick="getvalue()" value="2">
<input type="radio" id="banswer2" name="answer2" onclick="getvalue()" value="3">
```

now suppose if i click on any of the radio button .. it needs to call a function getvalue() which will fetch the text of the previous heading h3 and store it in the hidden fields value..
Can you provide me with a solution..?

I have got a script which gets the text of all the heading h3 in the page. Instead i just need to fetch the previous heading.

Note: I am using the same id banswer1, banswer2 for a reason.. please ignore that.

Comment: FYI id's should be unique.

Comment: yes i know sir.. i told u im using it for a reason.. ill change it later on.. its just for testing purpose..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use [prevAll](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rk1hjvqg/)

```js
$("[type='radio']").change(function ()
{
    var hidden = $(this).prevAll("[type='hidden']");
    var h3 = $(this).prevAll("h3");
    hidden.val(h3.text());
    alert(hidden.val());//Test remove in your code 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Question 1</h3>
<input type="hidden" id="getques" value="" name="ques1">
<input type="radio" id="banswer1" name="answer1"  value="1">
<input type="radio" id="banswer1" name="answer1"  value="2">
<input type="radio" id="banswer1" name="answer1"  value="3">

<h3>Question 2</h3>
<input type="hidden" id="getques" val="" name="ques2">
<input type="radio" id="banswer2" name="answer2"  value="1">
<input type="radio" id="banswer2" name="answer2"  value="2">
<input type="radio" id="banswer2" name="answer2"  value="3">
```

Comment: hey thanx fabio.. it works perfectly :)

just if you could help me with one more thing...?
the value fetching on clicking the radio button twice.. that is one click on first one doesnt get it, clicking other gets the value.. i used document.ready.. but its still not working.. help me out?

Comment: my code...
<script>
function getvalue(){
$(document).ready(function(){
$("[type='radio']").change(function ()
{
var hidden = $(this).prevAll("[type='hidden']");
var h3 = $(this).prevAll("h3");
hidden.val(h3.text());
//alert(hidden.val());
});
});
}
</script>

Comment: post another question thus I can help you. The code is difficult to read

Comment: ive posted a new question 
u can check it out here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675590/calling-the-function-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

If I have understand you, you can do it like this:

**EDITED**

changed closest to prev and find to next, as mentioned by @Dhaval Marthak

```
function getvalue(){
    //find h3
    var h3 = $(this).prev('h3');
    //get text
    var text = h3.text();
    //find hidden
    var hidden = h3.next();
    //set value
    hidden.val(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
$('input[type=radio"]').on(function () {
    var self = $(this),
        head = self.prevAll('h3:first'),
        hidden = self.prevAll('input[type="hidden"]:first');
    hidden.val( head.text() );
});
```

References:

- [`:first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/).

Comment: This will not work sir, I'm testing it! If we click on the 2nd question radio buttons it will return `h3` for the first everytime!

Comment: Hmm, I'm surprised; could you try the updated approach using the `:first` selector? I'm not sure, but I think the selector should return the first match encountered during traversal, whereas the method *may* return them into the order within the DOM. But I'm not certain, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes i've also checked the other solution you updated it's still not working, but there should be a way to figure it out but if we consider the traversal from bottom to top it should check for the `:first`. But still i'm also surprised.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Albet's code but instead of `closest()` you should use the `prev()` function.

```
function getvalue(){
    //find h3
    var h3 = $(this).prev('h3');
    //get text
    var text = h3.text();
    //find hidden
    var hidden = h3.find('input[type=hidden]');
    //set value
    hidden.val(text);
}
```

According to documentation `closest()` will:

> Get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors.

but what you really want is to get the first sibling of your input.

Comment: `hidden` isn't inside `h3` you don't need to `find()` it, just get it same as you're getting `h3`!

Comment: as dhaval said... prev isnt working.. hidden is not inside h3.. they are following line by line.. no parenting..